# Django: how to create object with Tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have a threaded mptt comments model to use with my BlogItem model:

```
class MyComment(MPTTModel, Comment):
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by=['-submit_date']
    class Meta:
        ordering=['tree_id','lft']
```

For tastypie i made Resource

```
class MyCommentResource(ModelResource):

    # i tried to use this commented strings (and of course i created related resources)
    #comment = fields.ForeignKey(CommentRosource, 'comment', null=True, full=True)
    #site = fields.ForeignKey(SiteResource, 'site', null=True, full=True)
    #content_type = fields.ForeignKey(ContentTypeResource, 'content_type', null=True, full=True)
    #children = fields.ToManyField('self', 'children', null=True, full=True)
    #content_object = GenericForeignKeyField({BlogItem: BlogItemResource}, 'content_object', null=True, full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = MyComment.objects.filter(level=0)
        resource_name = 'myComment'
        include_resource_uri = False
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put']
        include_resource_uri = False
        filtering = {
            'object_pk': ALL,
            'level': ALL
        }
        authorization= Authorization()
```

After that i have working api for GET requests fo MyComment model (i can see all comments (commenter's name, comment text, mptt level, pagination etc)

But when i try to make curl (or js) erquest:

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"comment":"sdfsdfsdf"}' http://myhostname.com:80/api/v1/myComment/ > /tmp/err.html
```

I get error "current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block" or other errors ("DoesNotExist at /api/v1/myComment/ No exception supplied", "Cannot assign None: "MyComment.content_type" does not allow null values." - but in request i POST {"content_type":{"id":"15"}} or link to content_type in my api that also works great).

For other, more simpler models (without generic relation, but with ForeignKeys) i can make curl requests and get "201 created" response, so i think i have error related to "generic" comments model

I'm doing wrong? Is there any docs or manuals - how to create object for "generic" model via tastypie?

Comment: Can you add the source of your Comment model?

Comment: i haven't any additional fields in MyComment model, i use inheritance from contrib.Comment default model and MPTTModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the built-in `Comment` model, then `GenericForeignKey` is not nullable, which is throwing the exception you are seeing. The `GenericForeignKeyField` on your resource specifies `null=True`, causing Tastypie to allow the null value to be passed to the ORM.

You can specify a value for the `GenericForeignKeyField` via it's resource_uri, e.g., `{"comment":"sdfsdfsdf", "content_object": "/api/v1/blog_item/1/"}`.